# Sending response to JSP from Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have created a JSP, Servlet and Java page, but now trying to get the output of MyAlgorithm (Java Algorithm) and send it back to my JSP page. However it's not working...am I missing anything here?

Please ask me if the question is unclear.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());    
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s_LocalDate = request.getParameter("s_JavascriptDate");
        System.out.println(s_LocalDate);
        algorithm MyAlgorithm = new algorithm();
        MyAlgorithm.Days();
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/forwarding-from-servlet-jsp

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the value you are passing into an attribute so it goes with the response.

`request.setAttribute("algoAnswer", MyAlgorithm.Days());
request.getRequestDispatcher("pagewhereanswershouldappear.jsp").forward(request,response);`

On the page side you could use jstl to get the value from the attribute with ${algoAnswer}.

Here more about it https://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example